# Cannot add value into array in Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to add the word "Flag" into column "G" or Array [6] where the corresponding row shows a value greater than 0.5 in column "E" or Array [5]. Note, that Array [6] is empty and only the script can add a value there if condition is met.

Here is my attempt but it does not add the word "Flag" into the cell.
I appreciate any help or pointer. Thanks in advance!

```
function test() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  var rg=sh.getDataRange()
  var vA=rg.getValues();
   var g = [];

  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
      g[i] = [vA[i][6]]; 

      if(Number(vA[i][5])>0.5)g[i] = ['Flag']; {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,7,g.length,1).setValues(g);
}}}
```

**The error states:Cannot convert Array to Object[].**

Comment: What is the value of `va[i][6]`? If it isn't a range string like "A1" or "R1C15" then it's not a valid range.

Comment: @tehhowch there is no prefilled values in array [6]. These are all empty and the script is suppose to add a value there if condition is met. What am I suppose to do?

Comment: If its an empty value why cant you just say `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(vA[i][6]).keyName = 'Flag';`? Where is `setValue()` defined?

Comment: I am not sure if it is defined. Maybe that is the problem? Based on the code, there is no definition yet, right?

Comment: Can you loop through vA.length, place vA[i][6] = 'Flag' and then replace data range?

Comment: @TheWizEd Replace the data range with what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an amended version of your code that will work if all your data is plain values and not formulas.

Please note this will overwrite any formulas.

```
function test() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  var rg = sh.getDataRange();
  var vA = rg.getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < vA.length; ++i) {

    if (Number(vA[i][5]) > 0.5) {
      vA[i][6] = 'Flag';
      //change value of array element
    }
  }
  
  rg.setValues(vA);
  //set changed values to source range
}
```

---

#### Edit

This checks column F and makes changes to column G.
It will not overwrite the formulas in column F, but it will overwrite any formulas in column G.

```
function test() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();

  var checkRg = sh.getRange('F2:F' + lastRow);
  var flagRg = sh.getRange('G2:G' + lastRow);

  var checkVa = checkRg.getValues();
  var flagVa = flagRg.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < checkVa.length; ++i) {

    if (Number(checkVa[i][0]) > 0.5) {
      flagVa[i][0] = 'Flag';
      //change value of array element
    }
  }

  flagRg.setValues(flagVa);
  //set changed values to source range
}
```

Comment: One more question: I noticed how when I run this code, it removes formulas which were present in column F or array [5]. Is there any way with this code, to NOT remove these formulas in column F?

Comment: Have added another version to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is in columns A thru F and beyond G.

```
for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
  if(Number(vA[i][5])>0.5) vA[i][6] = 'Flag';
}
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange.setValues(vA);
```

Or if you only want to replace G.

```
var g = [];
for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
  g[i-1] = [vA[i][6]]; // Notice its an array
  if(Number(vA[i][5])>0.5) g[i-1] = ['Flag']; // Notice an array again
}
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,7,g.length,1).setValues(g);
```

Comment: Yes, I only want to add values in column G. So, the 2nd approach of yours if more suitable. When I adjusted my code (see original post), it still throws errors: "Cannot convert Array to Object[][]."

Comment: Sorry a indexing mistake on my part.  g[i] should be g[i-1];